Display the rate of change of a value that did not exist before in PromQL
I am trying to display the rate of failing Kubernetes jobs using the kube_job_failed metric. It will display 1 job failed, 0 if not. I had the plan to take the rate()and then aggregate using sum() which does not work:

Note that the first failing job happened a little while after 11:00, so something is happening.
I am assuming the problem is that the specific metric for the failing/successful job does not exist before it fails/completes. So the rate of change for all jobs is zero.
The closest I came to a solution is using the sum() operator but I can not figure out how to get the rate of change for the sum (=derivative?):
I would like to see a graph that spikes when a job fails. Can anyone help me with my queries? Basically I need the rate of change of the sum. The end result should look something like this:


Have you tried using increase() instead of rate() like sum(increase(kube_job_failed[5m]))  ?

I did. I think the problem is that nothing increases. The value for the specific job did not exist before and is just "1" or "0" when the job failed/succeeded and will not change.

In that case can you try with the delta() function. You can find more information here.
